# Chemical Kinetics(Hypothetical elementary reaction)

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image: So this is the question, hope someone can help.]

For a hypothetical elementary reaction(image).
Initially, only 2 moles of A are present. The total number of moles of A, B, and C at the end of 75% of the reaction is:

Answer (score 1):

$75$% of $2$ moles of A is $1.5$ mole. $1,5$ mol A produce twice as much of B or C. This makes $3$ mol of B and/or C. It remains $2$ - $1.5 = 0.5$ mol A. The total number of moles is $3 + 0.5 = 3.5$ mol. Where is the difficulty ?

Comment: Thank you and sorry if this question felt too easy.